# Wordpress error 404 not found

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm having problems with WordPress.

I can see the front page, but when I try to open a link or a picture it always shows the same error:

> 404 Not Found
>
> The requested URL (X) was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at (X) Port 80

I took the WordPress site from one server to my server, and now it's not working on my server and the WordPress in the old server is working, but on mine it is not.

I've tried all of your solutions but I can't get it working.

Any help please?

Comment: flush your permalinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i could fix it ,

what i did is to reload de ae2enmod

Command : sudo a2enmod rewrite

Thanks to everyone who helped me.

Walle

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have move your website to a new a server. With that being said you need to update your permalink structure. That'll be update your .htaccess and your site will be up and running. Log in to your **wp-admin** and navigate to ***Settings -> Permalinks***. Review the structure if required and hit **Save** Changes. Test your site!

Comment: i updated my perman link and it didn't fix it, i am trying to find the solution

Answer (score -1):

set my permissions then uploaded an `.htaccess` file for the fix.

I didn't have an `.htaccess` file created on my server, so I made one and uploaded based on [this article](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/why-you-cant-find-htaccess-file-on-your-wordpress-site/)